# vscode - ofstream not creating a new file, .exe works normally

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, fstream, mingw-w64

I cannot create or read files using vscode with fstream. Program run from .exe works normally (creates a file empty.txt).
main.cpp:

```
#include <fstream> 

int main()
{
    std::ofstream file("empty.txt");
}
```

The above program does not create a file when run with vscode.

- Editor: Visual Studio Code
- Compiler: MinGW-w64 (MSYS2)
- System: Windows 10

launch.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}\\**.cpp",
                //"${fileDirname}\\**.h",
                //"${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Its probably in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

Comment: `"cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin",` in `configuration.json` should probably be `"cwd": ${fileDirname}`  ??

Comment: I am very confident that ofstream is working just fine, and it does exactly what it's told to do.

Comment: @tkausl The files are indeed created in the path you specified. How can I get the compiler to create a file in a folder with a .cpp file?

Comment: @Giogre With the change you suggested, I'm getting an error: 'ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `cwd` in both `launch.json` and `tasks.json` to `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",`.

See also [the official how to](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference).

Comment: After those changes I get the building error: _The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1._
If I choose to debug anyway, debug console gives error: _ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135._

Comment: Follow the tutorial to properly config gcc in windows https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw . By the way it said there to set `cwd` to `"cwd": "${fileDirname}",` in both files